# JSF + Hibernate: Collection is not associated with any session

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

First of all, I use Java EE, Hibernate with EntityManager and PrimeFaces.

I have one EJB module (business logic and domain) and two WAR modules (Jersey WS and JSF PrimeFaces).

I decided to initialize lazy collections in JSF WAR module to avoid lazy initialization exception. I don't use extended entity manager.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "company")
@SessionScoped
public class CompanyBean {

    @EJB
    private CompanyFacade cf;

    ...

    public String showDetails(Long id) {
        company = cf.find(id);
        Hibernate.initialize(company.getCompanyTypes());
        Hibernate.initialize(company.getPrimaryUser());
        Hibernate.initialize(company.getBlocked());
        Hibernate.initialize(company.getAddresses());
        Hibernate.initialize(company.getContacts());
        return "DETAILS";
    }

    ...
}
```

And I get:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.Hibernate.initialize(Hibernate.java:417)
    at minepackage.CompanyBean.showDetails(CompanyBean.java:79)
        ...`

I don't understand it. There has to be a session when one line before the initialization it was fetched from database, doesn't it? I initialize attributes in WS module in similar way and there it's working.

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the session is closed after your EJB finished, so the objects are in *detached* state. So `Hibernate.initialize()` won't work any more. You have multiple options here:

- Open the transaction on the client side (in your JSF bean or in a servlet filter). This way the session will still be open when your are calling `Hibernate.initialize()`.
- Modify your EJB to load the full object and all the required collections. You could use fetch joins and/or use `Hibernate.initialize()` there.
- Create a more fine grained API in your EJB. Method like `CompanyFacade.getAddressesByCompany()`.

I would prefer a combination of the latter two. Use fetch joins to load the one-to-one and many-to-one relationships in your `find` method and add extra methods for loading the one-to-many collections (like addresses). This will also improve performance of your backend because it reduces the number of database queries.